# push a folder containing multiple git repository up to github

Tags: git, github

I have a folder that contains multiple git repositories. I want to push all of the git repositories to github as a single repository, as I don’t want to have too many separate repositories on github.

For example, my projects directory tree:

```
projects  
├── .git  
├── some files or dir  
├── project1  
│   ├──.git   
│   ├──some files or dir  
├── project2  
│   ├──.git  
│   ├──some files or dir  
├── ...  
.  
.
```

There are some problems with it. One is that when I change something inside a child repository e.g.project1, I will have to commit inside project1 as well as the parent repository project.
It duplicates all the commit history in the child repos as well as the parent repository.

I have read about git submodule and git subtree.

git submodule:
I read about that if I use git-submodule. when I push the parent repository, the submodule won’t push together.
Also, how to add local repository path as git submodule? Is the local path saved inside .gitmodules?
If I change my local repository path or I want to push the local repository to remote and change the path to remote url? How can I change the reference afterward?

git subtree:
If I use git subtree, it seems to copy all the commit history of each sub-repository to the parent repository, and manage all the sub-repository as a whole, which is not I want to do.
I would like each project have there own git, so I can easily add, delete, move the projects around.

What are some simple ways to handle this monorepo?

Comment: "*push all of the git repositories … as a single repository…I would like each project have there own git…*" Contradicting requirements. Either you have these repositories separated and push them separately. Or you have a monorepo with all the histories combined into one history.

Comment: If I combine the histories, can I split them afterward? By using filter-branch?

Comment: Yes but it would be hard. `git subtree` is much simpler for both combining and splitting.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct in pointing out that having repos embedded in a repo leads to complications such as a commit in each repo.

If these are in sub-directories for specific reasons, and you want to track them separately, then they might be candidates for submodules.

Submodule changes do have to be pushed separately. As phd pointed out, you have to choose between a monolithic history or separate histories.

Submodules can be useful when the submodules are maintained as separate entities. For example code from a vendor that doesn't change frequently, or a HAL layer that is maintained as a service layer for the supermodule (the main repo).

To answer the question: "Also, how to add local repository path as git submodule? Is the local path saved inside .gitmodules?"
the git submodule init command will set up the submodule repo, and also create entries in the supermodule that let the supermodule know where the submodule is, and what commit from the submodule is considered current.

This is not the place for a complete turtorial on submodules. They can be tricky to use, so you should study the documentation on them carefully before deciding to use them.

Some people find them very useful, and some people hate them. I think it depends on if you are using them for an appropriate purpose, and know the proper procedures.

Comment: It’s mostly my projects. I am considering if git can categorise the commit history based on different projects like adding tags, and later on, I can extract the commit tree related to that project, and detach the project completely to separate git.

Comment: A situation like, I want to open source parts of my big project, but retain all the commit history related to those parts.